# What are the cases to be considered while parsing a mathematical expression(brackets)?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have to check if {} [] and () are properly matched.
I found these three cases of prime concern:

1.Two brackets not correctly matched.

2.Opening bracket available but not the closing one.

3.Opening not available but the closing one.

Are these the only cases to be taken into account?

I'd like the code for a parser/regex to make sure the characters are properly matched to be in Java.

Comment: It would help if you clearly identified the problem (rather than just a concern) with examples and expectations along with (at a bare minimum) the language definition for the math expressions you are using.  And all that said, your question is likely a duplicate of [Parenthesis/Brackets Matching using Stack algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16874176/289086) which is the top result from [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=matching+brackets+stack+overflow).