# Java String S="{({)}}"

Tags: java

Hi I have a String like --String S="{({)}}"-- 
I want to write logic where if a bracket opens it should be closed in that sequence if not return false.

For e.g
1.
S="{({)}}"
it is "true" as { bracket got closed in correct sequence manner.

2.S="{([)}]"
it is false as "[" should have been closed before "}"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874176/parenthesis-brackets-matching-using-stack-algorithm

Comment: Are you sure your first example is correct? `{({)}}` does not look "closed in correct sequence manner" to me