# Iterating the same method on a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string and I want to iterate the *.replace(re,'')* until I achieve and empty sting "". How to do this rather than repeating over and over again the same method

```
var isValid = (s)=> {
   const re = /(\(\))|(\[\])|(\{\})/gi
   return s.replace(re,'').replace(re,'').replace(re,'').replace(re,'') !='' ? false :true
  
};

console.log(isValid("[({(())}[()])]"))
```

Comment: Would [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) help here?

Comment: To rephrase (if I'm not mistaken) you want to **recursively replace/remove**  brackets that have a ***"valid"*** closing bracket?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan exactly.

Comment: There are many posts online that discuss solving this type of problem. Just Google for "balanced parentheses algorithm". Most of them use a stack to do this. Here is an SO question that discusses this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874176/parenthesis-brackets-matching-using-stack-algorithm.

Comment: Note that the stack approach solves this in O(n) instead of your O(n^2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a while loop.

```
var isValid = (s)=> {
   const re = /(\(\))|(\[\])|(\{\})/gi
   while(re.test(s)) s = s.replace(re, '');
   return s === '';
};
```

Comment: Even better (IMO) `while (re.test(s))` since `test` returns a Boolean.